# Transparent title bar in WinUI 3 app (Windows 11)

Tags: visual-studio-2022, winui-3, windows-11, winui, windows-app-sdk

I develop some UWP apps to Windows10 and I want put the tile bar transparent in a new app developed in WinUi3.

If I try this
`ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;`
The minimize, maximize and close buttons disappear, and I cannot move the app in my Window.

But in UWP it was more simple. I can put the title bar transparent (or with the same color of my app) without any problem, something like this:

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.Black;
```

It is possible something like that in WinUi3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar?view=winui-3.0#Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Window_SetTitleBar_Microsoft_UI_Xaml_UIElement_):

> If you set `ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar` to true but do not call
> `SetTitleBar`, the system title bar is restricted to the caption
> buttons and a small area next to the caption buttons that is reserved
> for title bar behaviors. However, your custom title bar element does
> not get title bar behaviors, such as drag and the system menu, until
> `SetTitleBar` is called with a valid `UIElement`.

Set the transparency by setting the value of [UIElement.Opacity Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.uielement.opacity?view=winui-3.0#microsoft-ui-xaml-uielement-opacity):

The value between 0 and 1.0 that declares the opacity factor, with 1.0 meaning full opacity and 0 meaning transparent. The default value is 1.0.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand. Can you give me an example, please? Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Color and transparency in caption buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=winui3#color-and-transparency-in-caption-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows App SDK team offers great samples in GitHub. You should take a look at the **Windowing** sample app.

https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/Windowing/cs-winui

You can also check my videos about customizing the `TitleBar`, if you're interested in.

https://youtu.be/rhYdNuBkqtE

**UPDATE**

I' so sorry Luís. The sample from the Windows App SDK team on GitHub seems to work only on Windows 11.

[Windowing - TitleBar sample - Titlebar always null #116](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/issues/116)

I'm sure they are working to target windows 10 either, but for the moment, you might need to do the way I suggest on my video.

Comment: Thank you. I try different ways but always show the error "_mainAppWindow was null"

Comment: Did you get that error on the **Windowing** sample app from the Windows App SDK? If it's only on your app, you might be missing some part in the **AppWindowExtensions**  class.

Comment: My target is only Windows11